# Symfony DataFixtures set default values

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, sql-update

I want to set an initial AdminUser in my website. When I load it to the database it fails to upload because of the "updateAt" field. I get the following error when I leave setUpdatedAt blank:

```
 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'updatedAt' ca
 nnot be null
```

Any value I set in the Fixtures File fails, I get the following error: (I tried to input the actual date in this example)

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '"2014-12-26 21:01:40"' (T_CONSTANT_E
NCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

Here is the Data Fixtures File:

```
<?php

namespace Usuarios\AdminBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Usuarios\UsersBundle\Entity\User;

class LoadUserData implements FixtureInterface
{
/**
* {@inheritDoc}
*/
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
    $userAdmin = new User();
    $userAdmin->setUsername('Admin');
    $userAdmin->setPlainPassword('1234');
    $userAdmin->setEmail('admin@web.com');
    $userAdmin->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    $userAdmin->setEnabled('1');
    $userAdmin->setUpdatedAt(\"2014-12-26 21:01:40");

    $manager->persist($userAdmin);
    $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

I tried to inpud data in the updatedAt in many different types but I cannot get the right data type or get the code to leave it blank.

Here is the Entity code for UpdatedAt:

```
<?php

namespace Usuarios\UsersBundle\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="0_00_users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser

/**
 * @var datetime $updatedAt
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(name="updatedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $updatedAt;

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 * @return User
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}
```

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `$updatedAt` value.

This should be the Doctrine way of doing it. Remove the logic that you do not want.

```
/**
 * //...
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends BaseUser

    // ...

    /**
     * Tell doctrine that before we persist or update we call the updatedTimestamps() function.
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps()
    {
        if ($this->getCreatedAt() == null) {
            $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        } else {
            $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date must be a valid \DateTime, not a string.  Try this:

```
$userAdmin->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime("2014-12-26 21:01:40"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the 'new' tag.